# laravel: accessing items in components folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I feel like this is a really basic question but for whatever reason I cannot find the answer. If I use the `composer.json` file to include jQuery and Modernizr in my project, those libraries are placed in the `/components/` directory, outside the `/public/` directory. So I have `/components/jquery/jquery.min.js` and `/components/modernizr/modernizr.js`, which is great, but when I'm setting up `/app/views/layout.blade.php`, I can't very well include `../../components/jquery/jquery.min.js`, can I?

The relevant portion of my `composer.json` file:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "components/jquery": "*",
    "components/modernizr": "*"
}
```

Is creating symlinks really the only way?

Comment: Looks like a mixup with the installation via Bower, where did you read to put them in your main composer.json file?

Comment: I thought that's where all dependencies go?

Comment: Yeah I don't think the `component/*` packages really work too well with the way Laravel works, path-wise. Have a look at the [component-installer](https://packagist.org/packages/robloach/component-installer) package (which is what puts them in `components/`) documentation to see if there's a way to specify where it should put the components, and then change it to `public/components/` or something.

Comment: [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) is a Dependency Manager for PHP and not really for Javascript/HTML/CSS. For managing front end dependancies have a look at something like [Bower](http://bower.io/) or [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the comments, composer is a dependency manager for php, for the frontend dependencies you can use npm ( from node.js) wich is used by lots of libraries.

you have to create a package.json file in your /public directory and then write

```
{
  "name": "your-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "*"
  }
}
```

now go to the public directory and type:

```
npm install
```

for modernizr is not as easy because you don't have the package available through npm, you can read [this article](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-modernizr) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

With composer you can install packages with a custom path

Like this:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md